# find height of children, give largest height to all others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some block level responsive lists. Everything is dandy unless one of the items has a bunch more copy than another. I can find the tallest li and give it's height to the other li's - but I want to limit this to each individual list only. I would also like to do this again if the user resizes but things get wild. Anybody deal with this before?  Thanks!

[HERE is a codepen of what I have so far](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/7d31e825bde9870b9b9e690070dd4d92)

```
/*var largestItem = -1; why negative one instead of 0 ? */

var largestItem = -1;

// I want to make this only affect the children of each list

$(".item-list li").each(function() {

  itemHeight = $('.item-list li').outerHeight();

  $(this).height(itemHeight);

  $('.number').text(itemHeight);

});




$(window).resize(function() {

  console.log("Resize event has happened. I don't know why, but alert is going haywire...");

  // I would like to listen for resize events and run the whole function again... 

});
```

Comment: What you need to do is iterate one time to find the greatest height, then after the iteration is done you can apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itemHeight = $('.item-list li').outerHeight();`

Problem here is that you are checking for a single value on a collection of eleemnts. jquery will only return the value of the first in that collection. In addiiton you aren't keeping track of which is tallest

```
$('.item-list').each(function(){
    var maxHt=0;

    $(this).children().each(function() {
      /* "this" is the current element*/
      var ht=$(this).outerHeight();       
       maxHt = ht > maxHt ? ht : maxHt;     
    }).height( maxHt);

})
```

Comment: take this code, wrap it in a function and use the function name within your window resize event and on page load.

Comment: Thanks for this and your explanation. I plugged this in, but I get the same outcome. li's in the second list are getting the same values as the first list.

Comment: OK...I didn't look at your demo close, to much ipsum lorem. Adjusted code with wrapper loop for each list

Comment: I had (this) to begin with but I replaced it to be extra clear - and in the process forgot why it was important. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: can only have `li` as children of a `UL`...not sure what issue is

Comment: Yes. There was an h1 in there by accident so I saw how it added that height to it as well, but it shouldn't have been in there. I wrapped in in a function and then called the function. Works great so far. Awesome. When I put that function in the `$(window).resize(function() )};` Things get wild. Any ideas?

Comment: need to understand that while manually resizing will fire many times... might want to throttle it a bit. Research throttling or debounce

Comment: Ah. I'm am looking into those things. http://www.paulirish.com/demo/resize  I don't really mind it firing because I want it to update the height as it scrolls. However, it appears to just be adding height instead of swapping it out. I'll look into giving it a height with .css() ?

Comment: ah yes...would have to `removeAttr('style')` before checking height

Comment: can chain that bewtween `children()` and `each()`...and Paul Irish is worth following... works at Google and is a guru when it comes to javascript

Comment: I pay attention to him. I tried his: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/  But ran into a bunch of issues. The box-sizing: border-box; seems to be an issue. After it checks again, the borders get added back into the height.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark your answer as correct since my "also i would like..." was pretty tacked on. Thanks so much. If you get a change, check out my pen again and see where it's at and if you know what might be the last part of the problem. Thanks again!